# Converting list of lists in dictionary python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm facing the following problem. I have a list of lists obtained from a remote URL with the following code:

```
import csv
import urllib.request

text_url = 'https://www.emidius.eu/fdsnws/event/1/query?starttime=1899-01-01T00:00:00&endtime=1899-01-31T23:59:59&minmag=4&maxmag=9&orderby=time-asc&limit=100&format=text'

with urllib.request.urlopen(text_url) as response:
   my_text = response.read().decode()

lines = my_text.splitlines()
reader = csv.reader(lines, delimiter='|')
```

I can convert the reader as a list of lists with:

```
my_list = list(reader)
```

What I'm trying to do is converting the list of lists (or within the `reader` itself) in a dictionary of lists. The items of the first list should become the dictionary keys while, from the second to the last element, I'd like to get the dictionary values as a list:

```
my_list[0] # dict keys
['#EventID',
 'Time',
 'Latitude',
 'Longitude',
 'Depth/km',
 'Author',
 'Catalog',
 'Contributor',
 'ContributorID',
 'MagType',
 'Magnitude',
 'MagAuthor',
 'EventLocationName']

my_list[1:] # dict values as list
[['quakeml:eu.ahead/event/18990105_0245_000',
  '1899-01-05T02:45:--',
  '41.500',
  '13.783',
  '',
  'AHEAD',
  'SHEEC',
  'CPTI04',
  '1309',
  'Mw',
  '4.63',
  'SHEEC',
  'Pignataro'],
 ['quakeml:eu.ahead/event/18990118_2048_000',
  '1899-01-18T20:48:--',
  '46.180',
  '14.500',
  '4.8',
  'AHEAD',
  'SHEEC',
  'RIBA982',
  '',
  'Mw',
  '4.51',
  'SHEEC',
  'Vodice Brnik'],
 ['quakeml:eu.ahead/event/18990122_0956_000',
  '1899-01-22T09:56:--',
  '37.200',
  '21.600',
  '',
  'AHEAD',
  'SHEEC',
  'PAPA003',
  '',
  'Mw',
  '6.50',
  'SHEEC',
  'Kyparissia'],
 ['quakeml:eu.ahead/event/18990131_1112_000',
  '1899-01-31T11:12:--',
  '66.300',
  '-19.900',
  '',
  'AHEAD',
  'SHEEC',
  'AMBSI000',
  '',
  'Mw',
  '5.80',
  'SHEEC',
  '[N. Iceland]'],
 ['quakeml:eu.ahead/event/18990131_2345_000',
  '1899-01-31T23:45:--',
  '60.100',
  '5.500',
  '30',
  'AHEAD',
  'SHEEC',
  'FEN007',
  '',
  'Mw',
  '4.60',
  'SHEEC',
  '[Biornafjorden]']]
```

Basically the output should be something like:

```
d['#EventID'] = ['quakeml:eu.ahead/event/18990105_0245_000', 'quakeml:eu.ahead/event/18990105_0245_000', 'quakeml:eu.ahead/event/18990105_0245_000']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `csv.DictReader` and `dict.setdefault`

**Ex:**

```
import csv

d = {}
reader = csv.DictReader(lines, delimiter='|')
for row in reader:                              #Iterate Each row
    for k, v in row.items():                    #Iterate Key-Value
        d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
```

Comment: A `collections.defaultdict(list)` is IMO a bit more readable than using `setdefault`.

Comment: @Graipher. So something like: `from collections import defaultdict`,  `d = defaultdict(list)` and finally replace the last line with `d[k].append(v)`, right?

Comment: @matteo: Yep, exactly.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
>>> result_dict = {}
>>> for idx, key in enumerate(a):
    for val in b:
        result_dict.setdefault(key, []).append(val[idx])
```

**Output:**

```
>>> result_dict
{'#EventID': ['quakeml:eu.ahead/event/18990105_0245_000', 'quakeml:eu.ahead/event/18990118_2048_000', 'quakeml:eu.ahead/event/18990122_0956_000', 'quakeml:eu.ahead/event/18990131_1112_000', 'quakeml:eu.ahead/event/18990131_2345_000'], 'Time': ['1899-01-05T02:45:--', '1899-01-18T20:48:--', '1899-01-22T09:56:--', '1899-01-31T11:12:--', '1899-01-31T23:45:--'], 'Latitude': ['41.500', '46.180', '37.200', '66.300', '60.100'], 'Longitude': ['13.783', '14.500', '21.600', '-19.900', '5.500'], 'Depth/km': ['', '4.8', '', '', '30'], 'Author': ['AHEAD', 'AHEAD', 'AHEAD', 'AHEAD', 'AHEAD'], 'Catalog': ['SHEEC', 'SHEEC', 'SHEEC', 'SHEEC', 'SHEEC'], 'Contributor': ['CPTI04', 'RIBA982', 'PAPA003', 'AMBSI000', 'FEN007'], 'ContributorID': ['1309', '', '', '', ''], 'MagType': ['Mw', 'Mw', 'Mw', 'Mw', 'Mw'], 'Magnitude': ['4.63', '4.51', '6.50', '5.80', '4.60'], 'MagAuthor': ['SHEEC', 'SHEEC', 'SHEEC', 'SHEEC', 'SHEEC'], 'EventLocationName': ['Pignataro', 'Vodice Brnik', 'Kyparissia', '[N. Iceland]', '[Biornafjorden]']}
```

Comment: That doesn't produce the desired result.

Comment: Not the result I'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

One naive option is this:

```
l = [["a","b","c"],[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
d = {k:[] for k in l[0]}
for i in l[1:]:
    dummy = {k:v for k,v in zip(l[0],i)}
    for k in d.keys():
        d[k].append(dummy[k])
```

Answer (score 1):

list can be rotated 90 degrees by `zip()`

```
d = {key:val for key, val in zip(my_list[0], zip(*my_list[1:]))}
```

Comment: That is also a nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve your problem without using dictionaries would be to load the CSV file into a Pandas data frame:

```py
import pandas as pd
import urllib.request

text_url = 'https://www.emidius.eu/fdsnws/event/1/query?starttime=1899-01-01T00:00:00&endtime=1899-01-31T23:59:59&minmag=4&maxmag=9&orderby=time-asc&limit=100&format=text'

with urllib.request.urlopen(text_url) as response:
    df = pd.read_csv(response, sep='|')
```

Now the data is in a structured format:

```py
>>> df
                                   #EventID  ... EventLocationName
0  quakeml:eu.ahead/event/18990105_0245_000  ...         Pignataro
1  quakeml:eu.ahead/event/18990118_2048_000  ...      Vodice Brnik
2  quakeml:eu.ahead/event/18990122_0956_000  ...        Kyparissia
3  quakeml:eu.ahead/event/18990131_1112_000  ...      [N. Iceland]
4  quakeml:eu.ahead/event/18990131_2345_000  ...   [Biornafjorden]

[5 rows x 13 columns]
>>> df['#EventID']
0    quakeml:eu.ahead/event/18990105_0245_000
1    quakeml:eu.ahead/event/18990118_2048_000
2    quakeml:eu.ahead/event/18990122_0956_000
3    quakeml:eu.ahead/event/18990131_1112_000
4    quakeml:eu.ahead/event/18990131_2345_000
Name: #EventID, dtype: object
>>> df.Latitude * df.Longitude
0     571.9945
1     669.6100
2     803.5200
3   -1319.3700
4     330.5500
dtype: float64
```

Comment: thanks. I did not specify that I need to do this without pandas, but great solution